# Not getting any HTML Response Codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am new to the whole scraping thing and am trying to scrape some information off a website through python but when checking for HTML response (i.e. 200) I am not getting any results back on the terminal. below is my code. Appreciate all sort of help! Edit: I have fixed my rookie mistake in the print section below xD thank you guys for the correction!

```
import requests

url = "https://www.sephora.ae/en/shop/makeup-c302/"
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.status_code)
```

Comment: `Print = (page)` is not how you print in python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the page you are trying to scrape protects against scraping by ignoring requests from unusual user agents.

Set the user agent to some well-known string like below

```py
import requests
url = "https://www.sephora.ae/en/shop/makeup-c302/"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you don't print to the console in Python with the syntax `Print = (page)`. That code assigns the `page` variable to a variable called `Print`, which is probably not a good idea as `print` is a keyword in Python. In order to output to the console, change your code to:

```
print(page)
```

Second, printing `page` is just printing the `response` object you are receiving after making your GET request, which is not very helpful. The `response` object has a number of properties you can access, which you can read about in the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the `requests` Python library.

To get the status code of your response, try:

```
print(page.status_code)
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting it! I should've probably reviewed my code before posting. Unfortunately, my terminal is still not showing any response codes. does it have to do with me not having any headers?